# How to get the first character of a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I am trying to get the first character of my char malloc like this:

```
char * str = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
            strcpy(str, op_mmin);
            char *temp6=NULL;
            strcpy(temp6,str[0]);
```

However, I am getting the following warning:

```
   warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   strcpy(temp6,str[0]);
   ^
```

Why can't I do str[0] to get the first char? I also tried to do this using ordinary arrays (eg. not a malloc) and I get the same error. How do I get the first char of this malloc (or array if you know that way too)?

Comment: Strcpy copies one char* into another char*. You're currently attempting to copy a char into a char*

Comment: `str[0]` is already the first character. If you just want the first character then that's the value you want. Also, you are trying to copy into a `NULL` buffer in the second `strcpy`.

Comment: Okay, So using *str[0] would work? Or maybe *str?

Answer (score 1):

Because str[0] is a character, not a string. And function strcpy must use two string (char *) as argument.

To resolve your problem, you can set temp[0] = str[0]; or use sprintf function, or use strncpy function

But you must allocate temp array before you want to use it.

Comment: Yes, but i said he must allocate temp array before use

Comment: @ringø that's not what the error message is for though

Comment: @bpgeck it's a warning. the error will come at runtime.

Comment: I've modified temp6 to be char temp6 = op_mmin[0]. Where op_mmin[0] is the first char in a char*. However, when I do, if(temp6==temp4)..and temp4 is just a char, I get the following error: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
   if(op_mmin[0]==temp4)

Comment: @ringø :  Thanks for mentioning this.. I have pointed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `char *temp6=NULL;`

Here you're trying to tell the compiler, "Hey ! set up temp6 as a pointer to char but don't allocate memory for it. "

If you do something like `strcpy(temp,str);` later you will get `segmentation fault` because you are trying to write to memory you don't own.

In your case you didn't go so far to see the segmentation fault, the compiler caught another error which is mentioned by the other answerer, ie in the line :

```
strcpy(temp6,str[0]);
```

where the compiler expected second argument to be char* but you passed char.

You have to allocate memory to the pointer first, or point it to an array. 
It is also possible to de-allocate the memory you have allocated for a pointer.

```
 char* temp= malloc(sizeof(char) * 10) ;  // allocating memory
 temp='\0'; // In essence de-allocating the memory.
```

Below is a complete example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

 main()
 {
  char* temp= malloc(sizeof(char) * 10) ; //allocating memory enough to store 10 chars
  char* str="abcdefgh"; // play safely - always store less than 10 characters. Consider that \0 will be appended to the end.
  strcpy(temp,str);
  printf("Temp : %s\n",temp);
  char* str1="ijklmnop";
  strcpy(temp,str);
  printf("Temp : %s\n",temp);
  temp='\0'; // In essence deallocating the memory.
  printf("Temp : %s\n",temp);
  strcpy(temp,str);
  printf("Temp : %s\n",temp);
 }
```

will give you the below result.

```
Temp : abcdefgh
Temp : abcdefgh
Temp : (null)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Also make sure that `free(temp6)` is placed at the end of your code to clean
up the memory. 
Though this doesn't directly answer your question, hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
char temp6 = op_mmin[0];
```

That's it! Now temp6 has the first char in op_mmin. Thank you all for your help.